# How do I use a PayPal PAYID?

Tags: paypal

I have been using the PayPal Java SDK, but unfortunately I'm not finding enough documentation. I've trid the code from [PayPal's GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call). After a successful run, I receive the following response:

```
{
  "id": "PAYID-1234",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "related_resources": [],
      "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "1.00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "state": "created",
  "create_time": "2020-03-18T08:50:04Z",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-123",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd\u003d_express-checkout\u0026token\u003dEC-ABC",
      "rel": "approval_url",
      "method": "REDIRECT"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-123/execute",
      "rel": "execute",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

From here, what should be the next step for the user to authorise the payment? Not sure if it's just me but I feel there isn't enough documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use that v1 SDK, it is old.

Use the v2 [Checkout-Java-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK).

For user approval use this front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

Once you have everything working well for the happy path, don't neglect to [handle funding source failures](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/), so that if the capture fails due to e.g. the buyer's first card being declined, this is propagated back to the UI and the buyer can select a different funding source.